# EMQ MQTT fails to run after successfull build on Raspberry Pi 2 B+

Tags: erlang, emq

Following instructions from: http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2017/02/28/install-the-emq-broker-also-known-as-emqttd-on-the-raspberry-pi-raspbian/ I built the latest version of Erlang and subsequently installed deps finally ran make successfully for emqttd broker (v2.3).

Now when I run the executable, I get the following output:

```
me@raspberrypi:~/emq-relx $ ./bin/emqttd console
./bin/emqttd: 20: ./bin/emqttd: runner_log_dir: not found
```

I did some research on Google and found some references to the `rebar` package using this variable after which I set it in `.bash_profile` and rebooted, but the error still persists.

What is wrong?

Comment: I am running the latest Raspbian, stretch!

Comment: The error seams to suggest it can't find the log directory, check what the default log location is, that it exists and that your user has rights to access/write that location

Comment: The variable wasn't defined by make, so I set it to ```/var/tmp``` and I tried running as root, but no luck. The same error persists.